# How can I Connect my Jira Account on GitHub Enterprise after already having done so on GitHub Cloud?

Tags: github, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I've recently completed the implementation on GitHub Cloud, and we also have GitHub Enterprise. I have a couple of questions:
Can we replicate the implementation on GitHub Enterprise?
Do we need to make any specific configurations within our Jira account for this transition?
Are there any other adjustments or considerations we should be aware of?
We require both implementations to be integrated with our Jira Cloud account.